# Data not passing in axios post request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm using `axios` to call a post request as follows:

```
axios.post(this.api+'&action='+this.action+'&wftkn='+this.wftkn, {name: 'Abcd'}).
   then((res)=>{

   });
```

When I check the network tab, I don't see the data being passed in the Request header. What would be the issue in this case?

[image]
Edit: added the console error.

Comment: no errors in console?

Comment: the server doesnt allow cors

Comment: https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Comment: Not as of now. But it should show the data in the request header. Right?

Comment: no it checks for cors first beofre sendeing request

Comment: your params are wrong encoded, do it `config.params` like shown in my *updated* answer

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Besides of CORS.. I would do the params stuff within the config object anyway..

Comment: I see. May be then that's why it's not working. Thanks

Comment: I'll have to call the api end point from the same host to avoid this CORS issue. Right?

Comment: this is a suepr simple dev server you can use in the mean time, i really like it https://github.com/typicode/json-server, good luck

Comment: ya or you can add cors hearders from php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
axios.post(this.api, { name: 'Abcd' }, {
  params: {
    action: this.action,
    wftkn: this.wftkn,
  }
}).then((res)=>{});
```

Comment: I edited the answer, should work this way, because your params are wrongly encoded when using as a string..

Comment: Okay will add this too.

Comment: I tried from the same host. It's showing any CORS issue. But I cannot see the data being passed in the request header.

Comment: weird, its what the docs are saying, we are using axios, but the non-alias version aka: `axios({method: 'POST', url: this.api, data: {...}, params: {...}})`

Comment: could you try your initial call again, is it working?

Comment: Let me try the non aliasing version.

Comment: Anyway, I'll try. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a protection from the browser, you're requesting a resource on a different domain, so you need to set a response header :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8000
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

Axios will work on most any web server when you use specific arguments.  Often time this issue occurs due to `GET` or `POST` conflict or faulty / missing headers.

````js
axios.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: `https://stackoverflow.com/end-point`,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'token'
  },
  data: {
    title: 'abc'
  },

})```
````